# Unable to Bubble user-defined Sql RAISERROR(...) to c# exception

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Unable to Bubble user-defined Sql RAISERROR(...) to c# exception.
Evidence or clues:  Sql generated errors bubble to c# but Sql user-defined errors do not bubble to c#.  Both are logged in the sql server logs.

```
EXEC sp_addmessage   
@msgnum = 50001,   
@severity = 16,  
@msgtext =   N'This is a user defined error message test_2_sp',
@lang = 'us_english';  
DECLARE @FirstNum int = 1
DECLARE @SecondNum int = 0
DECLARE @RowCount int
BEGIN TRY

   --SELECT @FirstNum / @SecondNum -- This sql error (not user defined) always comes through by itself with out try ... catch

   SELECT @FirstNum + @SecondNum as Result
   WHERE @FirstNum = 0 --Un-comment me and watch the error come and go???

   --SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
   --SELECT @RowCount AS '@RowCount' -- to see @@ROWCOUNT in SSMS

   --RAISERROR('OutSide', 16, 1) WITH Log;

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RAISERROR (50001, -1,-1) WITH Log; --https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max), @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int;
    select @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' LineNo ' + cast(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(5)), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    raiserror (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState) WITH Log;

END CATCH 
EXEC sp_dropmessage 50001, 'all'; 
END
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionStringName = "SQLUTLtest";
        //string con = @"Data...";
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName].ToString());

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Test_2_Sp", sqlcon))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlcon.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                Response.Write("Hello");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Response.Write("</br>finally");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think user defined errors must have a severity within a specific range. If your severity is outside of the user defined range then it will be reported as a general SQL error.

Comment: Yes, "When RAISERROR is run with a severity of 11 or higher in a TRY block, it transfers control to the associated CATCH block. The error is returned to the caller if RAISERROR is run:"  I am using 16 as I see most of the built in exception/error are 16 and they bubble up.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the same response as I did on EE (https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28979394/Bubble-user-defined-Sql-RAISERROR-to-c-exception.html):

I think the code will be unable to catch SQL standard Exceptions as well. For example, if I add a SELECT 1/0 (critical divide by zero error) after performing the addition, the code will continue to populate the Data Table and not catch the exception.

Can you update your C# code to the following? Basically, rather than just filling up the DataTable, I am trying to get a DataSet first. This would fail if an exception has been generated. (I tried this on a WinForms App, hence the MessageBoxes. Request you to update the code as necessary).

```
        using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Test_2_Sp", myCustomConnection))
        {
            mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstnum", "1");
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondnum", "0");

            myCustomConnection.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);

                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(myDataSet);

                if (myDataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt = myDataSet.Tables[0];
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ouch!");
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Good Bye!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nakul, somehow I missed this on EE.  It works!  Why does it work with "DataSet" and NOT "DataTable"?  I will close EE.

Comment: This is the first time I have used Stack for a question.  How do I properly clean my question up?